# How to install VirtualBox Guest Additions in a Lubuntu or Xubuntu virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, xubuntu

When trying to install Guest Additions in Lubuntu/Xubuntu, it complains about about not being able to update the kernel.

There are multiple solutions to this online, but what's the shortest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's quite a straightforward way, based on [this guide](https://www.easytechguides.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions/):

1. Launch the VM
2. Open the terminal
3. Type the following command:

   `sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms`
4. Press Enter.
5. Type your password.
6. Press Enter.
7. If you get an error (not just the ones in the original guide), type:

   `sudo apt-get install build-essential﻿`
8. Install (or re-install) Guest Additions by adding its internal CD
9. Restart the VM when requested
10. Eject the Guest Additions' CD

Comment: You ask / reply your own question in the same minute ???

Comment: [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Uxs.png)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, LWC! I have to say, the answer and the linked article are very similar; do you share any affiliation with the easytechguides site?

Comment: Not at all. I actually wrote it because they had some things wrong, like step 7 (they wrote it's only for specific errors, while for me it fixed a whole other error as well). Plus I feel they didn't make it short and to the point like here. Why did I lose points for making a helpful and straightforward answer I have no idea.